# How set a page title into Openui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to set the title of a page. I use this `js` code:

```
sap.ui.core.Core().byId("operationDetail").getController().changePageTitle("HELLO");
                console.log(sap.ui.core.Core().byId("operationDetail").byId("pageOperation").getProperty("title"));
```

The 2nd command returns "HELLO" correctly, but the page does not show the new title. How can I refresh the page?

Comment: I'm not even aware there is such a method `changePageTitle()` in sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller... Can you maybe post a link to the API where it's described?

Comment: This is a function that i call (in the target page controller):
`changePageTitle: function(p_pageTitle){
  this.byId("pageOperation").setProperty("title", p_pageTitle); 
    }`

Is the same that set the property externally

`sap.ui.core.Core().byId("operationDetail").byId("pageOperation").setProperty("title", "HELLO");
      console.log(sap.ui.core.Core().byId("operationDetail").byId("pageOperation").getProperty("title"));`

I have the same output (the console print HELLO) but the page title not refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong in your code... and although I don't suspect this is the cause of your error so can perfectly use the `setProperty` method, I think it's a bit cleaner to just use `setTitle`

What *is* odd, though, is your use of `sap.ui.core.Core()` which might be the reason you don't see your changes. The general standard is to use `sap.ui.getCore()` .

Have a look at this example: http://jsbin.com/hecuj/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I use .setTitle()     It work!!!
`sap.ui.getCore().byId("operationDetail").byId("pageOperation").setTitle("AAAAAA");`

(if I use sap.ui.core.Core()......setTitle() it work, too)
Yes .getCore() is bit cleaner! ;)

But my question is: why set property not refresh the page? If i set a property of other element (example "visible" of a butto) when I do `.setProperty("visibile", false)` immediately hide the button!

Comment: Yeah, sounds odd... If you think this is a bug, then I would recommend file a bug request